# dynamic content on document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I want to create loop on JS:

```
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
   document.querySelector("#a-page > div.a-section.askQuestionListPage > div:nth-child(7) > div > div > div:nth-child(i) > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > div.a-fixed-left-grid.a-spacing-base > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > span:nth-child(3)")
}
```

`div:nth-child(i)` - when i is changing

so the result will be:

```
   document.querySelector("#a-page > div.a-section.askQuestionListPage > div:nth-child(7) > div > div > div:nth-child(0) > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > div.a-fixed-left-grid.a-spacing-base > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > span:nth-child(3)")

   document.querySelector("#a-page > div.a-section.askQuestionListPage > div:nth-child(7) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > div.a-fixed-left-grid.a-spacing-base > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > span:nth-child(3)")

   document.querySelector("#a-page > div.a-section.askQuestionListPage > div:nth-child(7) > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > div.a-fixed-left-grid.a-spacing-base > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > span:nth-child(3)")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the question! What have you tried so far to make this work? You may want to look up string concatenation or template literals.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please review [ask] and provide a [mcve] when asking a question

Answer (score 0):

The ` instead of " let you do string interlopation: (And then use ${i})

```
for(let i=0;i<3;i++){
   document.querySelector(`#a-page > div.a-section.askQuestionListPage > div:nth-child(7) > div > div > div:nth-child(${i}) > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > div.a-fixed-left-grid.a-spacing-base > div > div.a-fixed-left-grid-col.a-col-right > span:nth-child(3)`)
}
```